# Draw OPE diagram

Tags: tikz-feynman

How to draw a textbook operator product expansion diagram like this?

[image]

In another word, how to make lines to have some kind of angle between each other and how to separate two points only a little bit?

The author suggested that I should assign the position of those points explicitly but is there someway I can do it within `\feynmandiagram`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal, but compilable code example (MWE) to help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I alluded to in the Github issue, the first and last diagrams won't really be (easily) feasible using just the `\feynmandiagram` command.  Having said that, the more verbose syntax is still quite simple:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (p1);
    \vertex [above right=of p1] (x) {\(x\)};
    \vertex [right=0.5cm of x] (0) {\(0\)};
    \vertex [below right=of 0] (p2);

    \diagram* {
      (p1) -- [momentum=\(p_{1}\), fermion] (x);
      (p2) -- [momentum'=\(p_{2}\), fermion] (0);
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (p1);
    \vertex [above=of p1] (0) {\(0\)};
    \vertex [right=of p1] (p2);
    \vertex [right=of 0] (x) {\(x\)};

    \diagram* {
      (p1) -- [momentum={[arrow shorten=0.3]\(p_{1}\)}, fermion] (x);
      (p2) -- [momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.3]\(p_{2}\)}, fermion] (0);
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (p1);
    \vertex [above right=of p1] (dot);
    \vertex [below right=of dot] (p2);

    \diagram* {
      (p1) -- [momentum=\(p_{1}\), fermion] (dot);
      (p2) -- [momentum'=\(p_{2}\), fermion] (dot);
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following outputs:

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]

[image: output 3]

The main thing I'm not sure of right now (and others are free to edit this answer if they know), is if there's a nice and easy way of making the little loop in the second diagram.  I suspect a similar question has been asked before, so if you forage through this site you might find exactly what you need.

Comment: Can I ask another question? I put your code into `align*` but then I can't get through compiling. If I use `$$` everything is fine, if I don't use math environment at all, everything is fine, if inside `feynman` I use `diagram` first instead of assigning `vertex`, everything is fine, so what could be the problem?

Comment: Most likely, it is because the `align*` environment has issues with empty lines (such as just before `\diagram*`).  You can either remove them, or put a `%` in the line so that LaTeX doesn't see the empty line (so that you can have slightly neater code).

Comment: OK, that solved my problem, txs. And really sorry keeping troubling you with these trivial questions.